# How to pass a partially inferred of full type to a macro?

Tags: generics, rust, macros

Petgraph is a cool Rust library for dealing with graphs. E.g. two nodes connected by an arrow labelled 2024

```
digraph { // Graphviz DOT syntax
    a [ label = "A" ]
    b [ label = "B" ]
    a -> b [ label = "2024" ]
}
```

would be written (with type inference from the add methods for the inner generic node and edge types) as:

```rust
use petgraph::graph::Graph;
let mut graph = Graph::new(); // Graph::<&str, i32>::new();
let a = graph.add_node("A");
let b = graph.add_node("B");
graph.add_edge(a, b, 2024);
```

Now I want to pack this (narrowed down from a bigger use case) into a macro. Since Petgraph has various implementations of graphs, I want to parametrize the exact type:

```rust
use petgraph::stable_graph::StableGraph;
macro_rules! graph {
    ($type:ty) => {{
        let mut graph = $type::new();
        let a = graph.add_node("A");
        let b = graph.add_node("B");
        graph.add_edge(a, b, 2024);
        graph
    }}
}
let g = graph!(StableGraph);
```

This `$type::new()` gives **types that don't start with an identifier need to be surrounded with angle brackets in qualified paths: `<`, `>`** and whether I do that or not **add missing generic arguments: `<N, E>`**

This works, but loses the nifty inference of the inner types:

```rust
let mut graph = <$type>::new();
…
let g = graph!(StableGraph<&str, i32>);
```

I have also tried `$type:path` but am facing pretty much the same issue. How can I make this macro accept both to-be-inferred partial types, as well as complete types?

*Edit:* for those who got curious:
[RustDOT: `graph! { A -- A -- B; A -- C; }`](https://github.com/petgraph/petgraph/issues/613)

Comment: Types are inferred *after* macros are evaluated, so you can't pass an inferred type to a macro. Your code does seem fine as a function though.

Comment: Replacing `$type:ty` with `$type:path` should work.

Comment: @PitaJ How? If it's a path, none of these are accepted $type::new() | $type<_, _>::new() | $type::<_, _>::new() nor <$type>::new() | <$type<_, _>>::new() | <$type::<_, _>>::new()

Comment: @cafce25 It's going into that match, so the partial type is ty. I was assuming the type would get replaced, before it parses that code. And then inferring could have happened. Very surprising to see I need to wrap <> because type starts with $…

Answer (score 3):

The generics must be provided but they can still be inferred. This code will work:

```
let g = graph!(StableGraph<_, _>);
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d0ef86808b664cd22cc57150b6a158b4)

Comment: Very nice, that works. It inspired me to match $type1:ident$(::$typen:ident)* and then do a somewhat hacky <$type1$(::$typen)*::<_, _>>::new()

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact answer because it doesn't involve macros, but consider instead using a generic function. It looks like the [`Build`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/latest/petgraph/data/trait.Build.html) trait might be suitable.  You can then use partially-inferred types with the function, for example `graph::<StableGraph<_, _>>()`.

```
use petgraph::{data::Build, visit::Data};

fn graph<T>()
where
    T: Build + Default,
    <T as Data>::NodeWeight: From<&'static str>,
    <T as Data>::EdgeWeight: From<u16>,
{
    let mut graph = T::default();
    let a = graph.add_node("A".into());
    let b = graph.add_node("B".into());
    graph.add_edge(a, b, 2024u16.into());
    graph
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I really need this in a bigger macro.

Comment: And by the way, I wouldn't call that inferring, as the where clause says exactly what types to use, and then you .into() those. By infer I mean automatically from the last add_* parameter.

Comment: @Daniel The where clause does not specify the types to convert _to_, it specifies the types in the body of the function to convert _from._ You can supply any type that can be created by conversion from `&str` or `u16` in this example. `graph::<StableGraph<String, i32>>()` will work, for example.

Comment: Ok, quite an interesting beast. But still far less than inferring, where I can really pass anything as last parameter to the add_* methods. Whatever (complex) type that has will become the <N, E> types of the graph.

Comment: @Daniel Well, yes, whatever types you use would have to be compatible with what's in the body of the function. I don't think this is really any different from the macro case, is it? You have `"A"` hardcoded in the macro, which is _more_ restrictive than the function in my answer. (Unless your macro is taking these values from the invocation site, which is not what appears to be the case in your question.)

Comment: https://github.com/petgraph/petgraph/issues/613 can now do real inferring, e.g. tuples with a silly weight function: `graph! { node [label = |id| (id, id.len())];  A -- "A" -- Bb -- r#Bb; /* a loop on A connected to a loop on Bb */ };`